# Easy way to increase GL_LINEAR radius?

Tags: opengl

I want to do a bilinear style filter with a larger radius, anybody know if there is some secret OpenGL command like the following that controls the parameters of the texture filter? In particular I want better texture scaling when viewing the texture from far away, and I am getting a good result from pythons `imshow` with a large radius.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Comment: You can generate the small mip maps yourself using the radius you want instead of letting OpenGL do it for you. That might give a similar effect.

Comment: @samgak Yes, but thats hard, and might not be optimal!